# acceleration of frictionless plane with mass sliding down the plane (Introduction to classical mechanics by Morin)

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

I am looking at this problem in Morin's *Introduction to classical mechanics*:

> **6.1. Moving plane**  A block of mass $m$ is held motionless on a frictionless plane of mass $M$ and angle of
> inclination $θ$ (see Fig. 6.8). The plane rests on a frictionless horizontal surface. The
> block is released. What is the horizontal acceleration of the plane?

Here is the more detailed diagram associated with the solution:

[image]

The quantities $x_1$ and $x_2$ represent the horizontal displacement of the plane and the block in their respective directions. Later on I switch to $q_1$ and $q_2$ to keep my sanity as I go through the Lagrangian and Hamiltonian.

The proposed solution sets out the Lagrangian in terms of the kinetic energy

$$
K=\frac12M\dot q_1^2 + \frac12 m ((\dot q_1 + \dot q_2)^2\tan^2(\theta) + \dot q_2^2)
$$

and gravitational potential

$$
V=-mg(q_1+q_2)\tan(\theta)
$$

where I have replaced $x_i$ in the diagram with $q_i$.

This yields the Lagrangian

$$
L=K-V=\frac12M\dot q_1^2 + \frac12 m ((\dot q_1 + \dot q_2)^2\tan^2(\theta) + \dot q_2^2)+mg(q_1+q_2)\tan(\theta)
$$

which, when processed with the Euler-Lagrange equations gives a solution ('after a little simplification')

$$
\ddot q_1=\frac{mg\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)}{M+m\sin^2(\theta)}
$$

(I did my best to process it with Sympy in python and got that solution as

$$
\ddot q_1=\frac{mg\tan(\theta)}{M \tan^2(\theta) + M + m\tan^2(\theta)}
$$

I think I see why it is equivalent after dividing top and bottom by $\cos^2(\theta)$, so I feel good that I have things set up right.)

To crosscheck things I also wanted to apply the Hamiltonian procedure, and so after replacing the $\dot q_1=\frac{p_1}{M}$ and $\dot q_2=\frac{p_2}{m}$

I had the Hamiltonian
$$
H=K+V=-mg(q_1 + q_2)\tan(\theta) + \frac12 m ((p_2/m + p_1/M)^2\tan^2(\theta) + p_2^2/m^2) + \frac12 p_1^2/M
$$

But processing this with Hamilton's equation $\dot p=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial q}$

I think that should mean that $\frac{\ddot q_1}{M}=\dot p_1=mg\tan(\theta)$ which (I  think?) is not the same as the one suggested in the solution in the book. This seems to be what I get both by hand and symbolically with Sympy.

So at the moment (no pun intended) I'm stumped as to what I'm doing wrong. Can I not use the time derivative of the momentum to check the acceleration like this?

Comment: What physical quantities do $q_1$ and $q_2$ represent?

Comment: Ah, good question. I'll edit in.  In short, horizontal displacement as was intended to be depicted in the diagram by the $x_i$'s.  The question asks for $\ddot q_1$.

Comment: Your error was in not using the canonically conjugate momenta.

Comment: @MarkSaving Neat, I knew there must be a reason. What's the translation for the non-physicists?  I gather i'm thinking about $p$ wrong.

Comment: The Hamiltonian as a function of $q_i$ and $\dot{q_i}$ does not capture the dynamics of the system as a whole. For example, in a constant magnetic field, the Hamiltonian is still just $\frac{1}{2} \sum m_i \dot{q_i}^2$ - exactly like if there were no magnetic field. The Hamilton equations apply to $q_i$ and $P_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$. In your case, you get a different canonically conjugate momentum than the "normal momentum" you get from $\dot{q_i} m_i$.

Comment: @MarkSaving OK that's ringing some bells... I guess I just didn't expect the $p$ to be so "different" from regular momentum.  Really you ought to give that as an answer since that's the simple misconception I'm having...

Comment: I have been swapping $p$ for $m\dot q$ for not a small amount of time, and apparently getting consistent results :(. This is the first "unusual" problem I tested it against...

Comment: @MarkSaving Is there no straightforward way to transform $H$ to be in terms of $p$?

Comment: @MarkSaving It seems odd to know "H and L capture the dynamics of a system"  and to know that L is written in terms of $q$ and $\dot q$, but on the other hand also say that "$H$ in terms of $q$ and $\dot q$ does not capture the dynamics."  I guess that just means "the H I used by naively replacing q with p/m".  I just did not translate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misconception OP is having is the approach to the Hamiltonian method.

The Hamilton equation $\dot{p_i} = - \frac{\partial H}{\partial q_i}$ does not apply to the "ordinary momentum" $p_i$. It instead applies to the canonically conjugate momentum, which is defined as $p_i = \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q_i}}$.

In simple cases, the part of the Lagrangian that depends on $\dot{q}_i$ is $\frac{1}{2} m_i \dot{q_i}^2$, so the canonically conjugate momentum is indeed $m q_i$. In this case, however, the canonically conjugate momenta are

$p_1 = M \dot{q_1} + m \tan^2\theta (\dot{q_1} + \dot{q_2})$
$p_2 = m (\dot{q_2} + \tan^2 \theta (\dot{q_1} + \dot{q_2}))$

As you can see, there is some annoying entanglement going on here between the two variables. This is reflected by the fact that energy depends on $(q_1 + q_2)^2$, in part.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Is there no smooth way to write down the Hamiltonian from the initial picture? I had wanted to do it both ways, but I don't see how to do it with canonically conjugate momentum. In fact, since seeing this example where momentum stops being mass times velocity, I've pretty much lost all grasp on how this is supposed to be used to solve a problem..